# Creating a LP Constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints, linear-programming, integer-programming, pulp

Below I have summarized how my outputVar should behave with DecisionVar:

```
Entity EntityValue DecisionVar1 OutputVar1 DecisionVar2 OutputVar2
A        5           1           5(base)     1            5(base) 
B        2           1           5(=prev)    1            5(=prev)
C        3           1           5(=prev)    2            5(3+2)
D        4           2           9(4+3+2)    2            5(=prev)
```

**Scenario 1**:
Since A, B, C are all allotted 1, each outputVar is set to base(=5), while D is the sum of the rest of the values.

**Scenario 2**: 
Since A and B are allotted 1. outputVar is set to base same as A, while for C, the value is the sum of the previous remaining values and since D is set same as C, its outputVar is set same as C.

**Context**: If certain entities are grouped together, we are trying to constraint the time allotted to process those entities. For group of entities(except the base) the time remaining is the time from the first of the previous group to the first of the current group.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easier ways to do this is to redefine your problem in terms of the groups of entities and model it as a set partitioning/ set covering problem.

Comment: To do that, I need to figure out a way to write the OutputVar(time) as an algebraic equation. I was thinking can I use Generic Algorithm and write a custom function that computes OutputVar to avoid writing an explicit linear or non linear equation. What are your thoughts?